# make height of WebView (webview_flutter) the height of webpage

Tags: flutter

I would like to have multiple WebViews (from the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin) in my flutter app on the same page. I want to have each page be loaded so that the height of the container is the same as the height of the web page.

Here's what I have so far:

```
ListView(
   children: <Widget>[
      Container(
         height: 500,
         child: WebView(
            initialUrl: urlA,
         ),
      ),
      Container(
         height: 500,
         child: WebView(
            initialUrl: urlB,
         ),
      ),
      Container(
         height: 500,
         child: WebView(
            initialUrl: urlC,
         ),
      ),
   ]       
)
```

Obviously, this loads 3 webviews each with a height of 500. However, I don't want to have to define a height for each page, and instead have it set the height of the Container based on the height of the actual page. (ie. urlA has a page with a height of 300, urlB is 250, and urlC is 600, so each container (or some other widget) has a height of 300, 250, and 600 respectively. Each container fits to be exactly that size. If at any point they go off the page, you can scroll with ListView.)

Comment: I have tried injecting javascript in the onPageFinished() callback to determine the height, but the I always retrieve the previously set height + some additional pixels: await _webViewController.evaluateJavascript('document.body.scrollHeight');

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no easy way of determining the height of the page displayed on the WebView. If the pages are predetermined and static, you may want to consider setting a fix height value if the page is displayed.

A workaround for this is by fetching the document height using Javascript, as demonstrated on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66477208/2497859).